# Inserting into a Trie, NULL pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, dictionary, null, trie

I have a specific question regarding the Trie data structure and what is going wrong with my code. Function parameter root always is NULL when I recursively call insert. Here is my code:

**Code:**

```
//subNodes is an array of TrieNode pointers that contains indices for all letters in the alphabet

bool insert(const string& word, TrieNode* root, int curI = 0)
//PRE:  word must be a valid word in a dictionary
//POST: True when a word is inserted into the Trie, false otherwise
{
    if(curI >= word.length())        //word has been scanned fully
    {
        root->isWord = true;
        return true;
    }
    else                             //word has more letters to be scanned
    {
        if(root->subNodes[word[curI] - 'A'] == NULL)    //if the current letter of the word is not in the trie
        {                                            //   insert the letter and advance the current letter of the word
            root->subNodes[word[curI] - 'A'] = new TrieNode(word[curI]);
            insert(word, root->subNodes[word[curI] - 'A'], curI++);
        }
        else                                         //if the currrent letter of the word is in the trie
        {                                            //   advance the current letter of the word
            insert(word, root->subNodes[word[curI] - 'A'], curI++);
        }
    }

}
```

I tested this by replacing `subNodes[word[curI] - 'A']` with `subNodes[word[13]]` (`13` is the index for `N` in the alphabet and I was testing the word not) and root was no longer NULL for that call. Therefore something is going wrong with the indexing. Does anyone know what is wrong? I considered using a C++ map or vector. Does anybody have any disagreements with using an array?

Comment: In C++ there's no guarantee about the order in which the parameters passed to a function are evaluated. So, probably, your compiler decides to pass in the old curI as the last param but uses the new (incremented) value as the index into word.

Comment: Not that its anything to do with your problem (others have already solved that for you), but I'd be refactoring your two recursive `insert` calls (which are identical) out of their `if/else` block, and having just a `if(root->subNodes[...] == NULL) root->subNodes[...] = new TrieNode(word[curI]);` followed by `insert(word, root->subNodes[...], curI+1);` (ellipses added for brevity). Just my 2c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean `++curl` - i.e. pass in the incremented value to the recursion call? As it stands you're passing the same value into each recursion since `curl++` is post-increment. It may be easier to just write `curl + 1` anyway since you don't need the curl value again.

Comment: Thanks! curI + 1 works because what @Eugen Constantin Dinca said about the function parameter order must be true.

Comment: Oops - I'd missed you were using curl again in same call. Yes, definitely `curl + 1` not `++curl`. Glad it works!

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here.

1. Between two sequence points if a variable is modified, the variable can be accessed only to determine the new value to be stored. In your code, when you call insert(), curI is incremented, and also accessed to pass as an argument. This is wrong.
2. C standard doesn't define function parameter evaluation order.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point

http://c-faq.com/expr/seqpoints.html

Following will fix the issue.

```
insert(word, root->subNodes[word[curI] - 'A'], curI);
curI++;
```